# Can't bind to style.clip-path in angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, clip-path

I have a simple component in Angular 4 that is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div [style.clip-path]="shape" [style.background-color]="color"</div>
```

and the only thing I have added to the .ts file is:

```
 color = 'green';
 shape = 'polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%)';
```

There is some styling that makes the `div` 400px by 400px.
When I serve this code I see a green box, meaning the style binding does work for at least `background-color`. However the box is still a square and not the pentagon that I defined. `clip-path` seems to not be set properly.

Weirder still I tested this with Angular 2 and it functions as expected.

Did something change from Angular 2 -> Angular 4 that would deny binding to particular style attributes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not working because it's being sanitized.

You need to use [`DomSanitizer`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer). From the docs:

> Calling any of the `bypassSecurityTrust...` APIs disables Angular's built-in sanitization for the value passed in. Carefully check and audit all values and code paths going into this call. Make sure any user data is appropriately escaped for this security context. For more detail, see the [Security Guide](https://angular.io/guide/security).

So, inject the `DomSanitizer` and use [`bypassSecurityTrustStyle`](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypassSecurityTrustStyle).

```
private _polygon = 'polygon(50% 0%, 100% 38%, 82% 100%, 18% 100%, 0% 38%)';

public get polygon() {
   return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this._polygon);
}

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
```

Comment: This completely fixed the issue, You would think there would be some kind of logging addressing this

Comment: It _is_ logged in the console.

Comment: Oh your right, it's just not marked red as if it was an error.

Comment: Keep in mind that you should not bind styles or other input properties to functions. Angular will have to call this getter frequently to determine if the value has changed. For one element it won't be too noticeable, but it can cause performance issues. Instead, store the return value of the sanitizer function in a variable and use that. I.e. `polygon: SafeStyle; this.polygon = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(this._polygon);`